# Why isn't VScode pwsh terminal able to see my azure resource groups?

Tags: azure, powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to tag all my running VMs from azure with tags from a CSV file but my PowerShell script is failing when being run from VSCode PowerShell core terminal.

I double-checked and I have set the correct active subscription (we have multiple tenants and subscriptions), but the output says that it can't find my resource groups (they are there for sure).

```
Enable-AzureRmAlias
$csv = import-csv "C:\Users\popes\Desktop\Jedox\Powershell scripts\Tagging\Tagging.csv"

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    # Retrieve existing tags
    $tags = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $_.RG -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -Name $_.VM).Tags

    # Define new value pairs from CSV
    $newTags = @{
        company     = $_.Company
        dns         = $_.DNS
        type        = $_.Type
        CN          = $_.CN
    }

    # Add new tags to existing set (overwrite conflicting tag names)
    foreach($CN in $newTags.Keys){
        $tags[$_] = $newTags[$_]
    }

    # Update resource with new tag set
    Set-AzResource  -ResourceGroupName $_.RG -Name $_.VM -Tag $tags -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
}
```

The output:

```
Get-AzResource : Resource group 'machine774_rg' could not be found.
At line:3 char:14
+ ...    $tags = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $_.RG -ResourceType "Mi ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzResource], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.GetAzureResourceCmdlet

Cannot index into a null array.
At line:15 char:9
+         $tags[$_] = $newTags[$_]
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Comment: well, first of all: all sorts of integrated terminals are garbage. secondly, can you verify you are in the correct tenant\sub and show the output for get-azresourcegroup

Comment: If I do az account show, it shows that I am in the correct subscription. However, if I do get-azresourcegroup it shows me RGs from the default subscription and not the current one.

Comment: you do understand that az cli and az powershell use different ways to auth?

Comment: Try to use [`Clear-AzContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/clear-azcontext?view=azps-2.4.0), then login with specific tenant and subscription, `Connect-AzAccount -Tenant "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" -SubscriptionId "yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy"`.

Comment: I haven't got the chance to test this yet. Will come back with feedback later today.

Comment: Ok, logging in with the correct command seems to have solved the missing rg issue. However, I'm still getting some weird error when running the script:

   `Unable to index into an object of type
    "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.String]".
    At line:15 char:9
    +         $tags[$_] = $newTags[$_]
    +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex`

Comment: Ok, I managed to make it work by removing the code that would force the overwriting of the new tags. Thank you for your help @Joy Wang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`Clear-AzContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/clear-azcontext?view=azps-2.4.0), then login with specific tenant and subscription, `Connect-AzAccount -Tenant "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" -SubscriptionId "yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy"`.